# ObjectConversionError when converting types with generics in Nim

Tags: generics, nim-lang

When I craft a simple class hierarchy such as:

```
type
  fooObj = ref object {.inheritable.}
  barObj = ref object of fooObj
  bazObj = ref object of fooObj
    x: string

var troz: fooObj

let bar = barObj()
let baz = bazObj(x: "yes")

echo bar[]
# ()
echo baz[]
# (x: yes)
troz = bar 
echo troz[]
# ()
troz = baz 
echo troz[]
# ()
echo bazObj(troz).x
#yes
```

I get the expected output (shown in line) when accessing the `x` member variable of the `bazObj` type.

When I craft a similar hierarchy but using generics the code compiles fine but throws an `ObjectConversionError` exception. Is my syntax wrong?  Or is this type of object conversion with generics not  supported in Nim?

```
type
  fooObj[T] = ref object {.inheritable.}
  barObj[T] = ref object of fooObj[T]
  bazObj[T] = ref object of fooObj[T]
    x: T

var troz: fooObj[system.string]

let bar = barObj[system.string]()
let baz = bazObj[system.string](x: "yes")

echo bar[]
# ()
echo baz[]
# (x: yes)
troz = bar 
echo troz[]
#()
troz = baz 
echo troz[]
#()
echo bazObj[system.string](troz).x
#Traceback (most recent call last)
#foo.nim(22)           foo
#Error: unhandled exception: invalid object conversion [ObjectConversionError]
```

If I replace line 22 with `echo bazObj(troz).x`, when I compile I get:

```
foo.nim(22, 13) Error: type mismatch: got (fooObj[system.string]) but expected 'bazObj'
```

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Either the first should throw an exception or the second should not, I'm not sure which, since you're trying to convert a null pointer, and it's not actually of the child type you want to convert it to.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I changed my approach slightly and went with object variants instead.  I'm still not sure if what I was trying above should work or not.

What I was trying to achieve was a basic `Option` or `Maybe` type that is available in Scala and other languages.

This is what I ended up implementing, it isn't exactly a 'real' `Option` type, but it works for what I want to do so far.

```
type
  OptionKind = enum
    okNone,
    okSome
  Option*[T] = ref OptionObj[T]
  OptionObj[T] = object
    isDefined: bool
    case kind: OptionKind
    of okNone: discard
    of okSome: x: T

proc None*[A](): Option[A] =
  Option[A](kind: okNone)

proc Some*[A](x: A): Option[A] =
  Option[A](kind: okSome, x: x, isDefined: true)

proc isSome*[A](x: Option[A]): bool =
  x.isDefined

proc isNone*[A](x: Option[A]): bool =
  not x.isDefined

proc get*[A: Option, B](this: A): B =
  if this.isNone:
    raise newException(NoSuchElement, "Failed to get from None")
  this.x

proc getOrElse*[A: Option, B](this: A, default: B): B =
  if this.isSome:
    this.x
  else:
    default

proc isEmpty*[A: Option](this: A): bool =
  not this.isDefined

type NoSuchElement* = object of Exception
```

Comment: This [PR](https://github.com/Araq/Nim/pull/2515) should be interesting for you. In the linked IRC discussion there is also an explanation why an object variant is inferior to a simple boolean + value. My first implementation looked very similar to yours :). Note that the `isDefined` is redundant, and it is probably not a good idea to make it a `ref` type.

Comment: Heh, looks like I came along at just the right time.  Looking forward to that pull request getting merged.

Comment: @bluenote10 thanks, checked out your code, very helpful!

Comment: @lokullin: Oh, I did not mean to take credit for that. It is all BlaXpirit work. I was only seeing a few issues that could hamper functional programming and proposed minor changes.